# Change virtualhost DocumentRoot based on cookie?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'd like to allow my users to opt-in to a new version of my website. Is there any way to make my domain point to a different DocumentRoot within my virtualhost configuration if a user has a particular cookie set? Or is there any other way to achieve the same result without having to setup varnish, nginx, etc?

Answer (score 1):

A cookie redirection would probably be the most efficient method. Set up the new website either inside of a new directory, or inside of a virtualhost with a different hostname prefix. Redirect them to the new location based on the presence of the cookie.

This looks like it may be close to what you want:
http://david.narrabilis.com/node/40

Comment: I'd like people using the new website to access it at the same domain, rather then a subdomain like beta.website.com, which is why I was hoping there was a way to do it at the vhost level.

Comment: If they get redirected to the equivalent functionality on the new site when accessing the normal site, there is not much difference to them without specific examples. Fairly commonplace on major websites. That said, do you have similar concerns with redirecting them into a subdirectory of your existing vhost per my other suggestion? That keeps the domain name the same. You can specify configuration blocks that only impact the new directory, i.e. <Location /subdir>